# Let's say I have an MRI scan of my brain. What exactly can I learn from it?

Tags: neuroimaging, neuroanatomy

Asking this because I participated in an MRI study today at my local University, and the compensation will be an emailed 'picture of my brain'.

*Note that I intend this question to be catered towards the general public, and not me specifically. Replace 'I' with any arbitrary person's name. :)*

Comment: Virtually nothing.

Comment: Well, you could discover that [you are missing your cerebellum](https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg22329861-900-woman-of-24-found-to-have-no-cerebellum-in-her-brain/)